# Call RESTlet form Suitelet with user's credentials

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have an internal Suitelet (at least I think I do... new to Suitelets, it is hosted in NetSuite). I try to use an internal url for my restlet, but every time I do, I get an error that I need a fully qualified URL for an http call. If I use the external URL, it works, but only if I pass my credentials in the header.

Is there any way to grab the user's credentials? Or to actually use the internal url and just keep everything inside with the current user's roles? The restlet creates records, and I'd rather that the owner be the user that is performing the action rather than me.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to do this in order to manage governance? If so why not put the control in a client script and call a series of Suitelets? What advantage are you hoping to achieve with RESTlets?

Comment: I haven't been able to get my calls to Suitelet's to work =( Also, I had already created the RESTlet, so I was just trying to use that. There's been a good deal of "scope creep" that has changed the requirements, unfortunately. Maybe I'll look into just running a client that calls a suitelet.

Comment: If you're starting the process from the NS UI then that would be the approach I would take. Calls to RESTlets from the UI should work without extra auth as well though Suitlets are the intended target for that.

Answer (score 3):

When using Internal URL, Its better to use `url.resolveScript` from URL Module

It **returns an external or internal URL string to a script.**

```
var output = url.resolveScript({
    scriptId: 'custom_script',
    deploymentId: 'custom_script_deployment',
    returnExternalUrl: false
});
```

Use HTTPS request in HTTPS module to send request

- For a RESTlet called from an external client, you can use OAuth or
  the NetSuite-specific method NLAuth in the HTTP Authorization header.
  OAuth uses token-based authentication (TBA) to access resources on
  behalf of a user, eliminating the need to share login credentials
  such as username and password. See Using OAuth in the Authorization
  Header.

  NLAuth passes in NetSuite login credentials such as company ID, user
  name, password, and role. See Using NLAuth in the Authorization
  Header.
- For a RESTlet called from a client hosted by the same NetSuite
  account that hosts the RESTlet, you do not need to pass
  authentication information in the HTTP request. A check for all valid
  NetSuite session cookies occurs, and this existing session is reused.

For more 
information see  [Authentication for RESTlets](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N2971402.html)

and [RESTlet URL and Domain](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N2971762.html)